# How do I get data to display in Angular from API in Express?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, express, get

I am trying to use Nodejs/Express as my back end for producing data from a database. I currently have an api route setup so that a database query will result in its directory. So if I visit localhost:3000/api currently I will see the following:

```html
{"status":200,"data":[{"Issuer_Id":1,"Data_Id":2,"Data_Name":"Name 1"},{"Issuer_Id":2,"Data_Id":14,"Data_Name":"Name 2"},{"Issuer_Id":2,"Data_Id":1,"Data_Name":"Name 3"}],"message":null}
```

This leads me to believe I have everything setup correctly on the back end.

Now how do I get this data to display on my Angular front end?

I have been through hours of tutorials and this is what I have come up with:

**nav.component.ts**

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { Series } from '../../data.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fixed-nav',
  templateUrl: './fixed-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fixed-nav.component.css']
})
export class FixedNavComponent implements OnInit{
  serieses: Series[] ;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getSeries().subscribe((serieses: Series[]) => this.serieses = serieses);
}
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class Series {
  Issuer_Id: number;
  Data_Id: number;
  Data_Name: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getSeries(): Observable<Series[]> {
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/")
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```html
import { Form1Module } from './modules/form1/form1.module';
import { FixedNavModule } from './modules/fixed-nav/fixed-nav.module';
import { HeaderModule } from './modules/header/header.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,           
    HttpClientModule,
    HeaderModule,
    FixedNavModule,
    Form1Module,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What do I need to enter in the nav.component.html to see the results?

Also note that when I refresh my angular page on lcoalhost:4200 I can see that the GET request is hitting the /apiu/ on the 3000 express server.

Comment: I have tried unfortunately nothing displays.

I have tried:

{{series}} , {{serieses}}, {{serieses | json }} {{serieses.issuer_id}},  {{serieses.issuer_id | json }}

Comment: Ok, are you sure your component receives the data correctly? What happens if you `console.log(serieses)` inside the subscribe of your component?

Comment: ok your pretty close and I have a very in depth answer for you to improve on what you have, but do you mind if I see your express route before I answer?

Comment: I am sorry -- I have only started with Angular/Express a week ago so I am unsure where to add this code. If you could tell me where I would really appreciate it. Also thanks for getting back to me so quickly.

Comment: Router below (masked the names):

router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
 var sql = 'SEL TOP 3 *  FROM db.table;';
 return db.read(sql)
  .then((users) => {
    response.data = users;
    res.json(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    sendError(err, res);
  });
});

Comment: Hey bugs -- I put that line directly inside the ngOnInit add it won't compile. Both the ";" after log(serieses) and the final "serieses" are underlined. 

With: ')' expected and Cannot find name 'serieses'.

Comment: My bad, try this:
 `this.dataService.getSeries().subscribe((serieses: Series[]) => {
      console.log(serieses)
      this.serieses = serieses
    });`

Comment: I added this and it looks to not have any errors but I am not seeing anything display in my terminal any different than before. Sorry this is proving to be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to help with best practices which might help get the intended result. I will amend this answer as we troubleshoot and hopefully arrive at the right answer.

So in your dataServices service I wanted to point out a couple things. Angular recommends we use the httpClient and not http and warn that http will soon be depreciated. I am fairly new to angular myself and have only ever used httpClient and have gotten great results so I recommend using that. I think this means that the promise that you are returned is changed too. Namely, you pust use a `.pipe` method inorder to use rxjs operators like map on the result. So this is what your dataService file would look like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class Series {
  Issuer_Id: number;
  Data_Id: number;
  Data_Name: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getSeries(): Observable<Series[]> {
    return this._http.get<Series[]>("http://localhost:3000/api/")
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return <Series[]> res
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Note that I have imported map in a different rxjs/operators.
In actuality you dont even need to pipe or map the return since you have already declared the type of return in the get method of _http. HttpClient will cast the return into a Series[] for you so this one liner: `return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/")` would work. I've written the code how it is however to console.log the return that your getting.

In the comments, could you tell me what is logged?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I changed my dataService page to match yours. However all I see in my output is: GET /api/ 200 389.782 ms - 261

Comment: So this leads me to believe that the request went through, just no data is retrieved. In your last `.then` statement in your express route for `/api` I think it should read `.then(users => { res.json(users.data) });` and then everything else after that

Comment: or maybe you could just return the `users` response likt `.then(users => { res.json(users) })` Sorry I'm not understanding what `response` is supposed to be doing since it is undeclared as far as I know and seems just to be a placeholder for `users`. So I'm guessing that you want to either return `users.data` or you want to return `users` as a whole... but thats just a guess...

Comment: Sorry here is the detail for response:

// Response handling
let response = {
    status: 200,
    data: [],
    message: null
};

router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
 var sql = 'SEL TOP 3 *  FROM db.tb;';
 return db.read(sql)
  .then((users) => {
    response.data = users;
    res.json(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    sendError(err, res);
  });
});

Does this help? Sorry I am still very new.

Comment: Theres no need to apologize, we are all new at some point. So when I'm trouble shooting across express and angular I like to console log what I send and what I recieve just to make sure they are the same on both ends. Before your `res.json(response)` call could you `console.log(reponse)`

Comment: Thanks! It came back WITH this:

GET /api/ 200 221.881 ms - 261
{ status: 200,
  DATA:
   [ { Issuer_Id: 2,
       Data_Id: 14,
       Data_Name: 'Name 1' },
     { Issuer_Id: 2,
       Data_Id: 4,
       Data_Name: 'Name 2' },
     { Issuer_Id: 2,
       Data_Id: 9,
       Data_Name: 'Name 3' } ],
  message: NULL }

Comment: If I go directly to the 3000/api on express it will load a new set of data as any time that page is touched it refreshes. So if I load data into the 3000/api by going to the change it will have X data.

When I refresh my angular on 4200 it will also pull data from the 3000/api that is the same format but it will not match X data as the results are now different. The underlying SQL returns different results each time.

Comment: ok well now we can be sure the req, is being processed correctly, and there is something contained in the res. Now, could you open your browsers dev tools and check the console to see what is logged there?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (FixedNavComponent.html:7)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14693)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13807)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)

Comment: Cool, I feel like we are getting somewhere. Now 2 questions? Is there anything presented before that? Like `undefined` or empty brackets `{}`.This would signal a reponse before the error? If not that means this is a runtime error that probably doesn't have to do with getting the repsonse. Second question is do you recongnize any of those documents, like FixedNavComponent.html? It seems there is something trying to read a data property there and that property doesn't exist so we get this error. I would take this line out and try and analyze my reponse in the console before displaying it

Comment: We are extremely close! So I put this into my html page which is the FixedNavComponent.html you metnioned.

`{{serieses.data[0].Issuer_Id| json }}`

And it displays in my angular page. However I still get the same error saying that it cannot read the property 'data'.

Comment: Yes. Ok so based on your earlier response your res has a property ‘DATA’ all caps. Have you making that all lowercase or getting the property if your series as an all caps DATA? But something else that worries me is that the sic sole should be logging the response before the error displays. Is there no logged reponse in the browser console?

Comment: I am now able to get the full JSON in my angular 4200 site to display as {{serieses}} with no  errors.

However when I try to access things like  {{serieses.issuer_id}} I receive an error in Chrome in the console. Everything looks right on the 3000 and the GET displays with the correct JSON.

I got rid of all of the data logic so my JSON now just comes across as: `[{"Issuer_Id":2,"Data_Id":3,"Data_Name":"Name 1"},{"Issuer_Id":2,"Data_Id":5,"Data_Name":"Name 2"},{"Issuer_Id":2,"Data_Id":10,"Data_Name":"Name 3"}]`

Comment: nice!! We've come a long way. Ok I think this is because serieses is an array. You could probably display `{{serieses[0].issuer_id }}`, but I doubt this is what your going for.  Instead you probably want to display a list of each individual series with a for loop (look up *ngFor). This would go something like this `<ul *ngFor="let series of serieses"><li>{{ series.issuer_id }} </li></ul>` You could use any amount of `<li></li>` elements to display as many properties as you want.

Comment: whoops, my bad, the *ngFor should go in the ul element... I've fixed it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you!!!!!!

Any idea how I could implement them to list in a form?

<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <ul *ngFor="let series of serieses">
                        <li><option>{{ series.Issuer_Id}} </option></li></ul>
                    <option>1</option>

Comment: Glad we got it working. Ok as for using *ngFor, you can use it in any parent group and the object can be referenced in any child group. For instance in a form you could say `<form *ngFor="let series of serieses"><label for="{{series.Issuer_id}}">{{series.Issuer_name}}</label></form` Not exactly what your trying to do but the point is that you can use the reference the object at any point within the parent object through interpolation (within double bracketts), or even as an attribute.

Comment: basically I'm saying it doesn't have to be contained in a ul/li format. Use it in a div, or form or whatever element that can contain other elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to correct your code I am providing my own setup **Works for Me**

In server.js

```
module.exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';
```

Now in App.js

```
var backend = require('./server.js');
console.log(backend.SimpleMessage); 
var data = backend.simpleMessage
```

In index html include App.js

```
<script src = '/App.js'></script>
alert(simpleMessage)
```

And you should get 'hello world'